# Can't using z-index CSS position

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

I create a Slick Carousel.

It auto generate two buttons next and previous image.

My code like this:
HTML:

```
<div class="slick-track slick-initialized slick-slider">
    <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" role="button" style="
    z-index: 999999 !important;
">Next</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slick-track {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #a94442;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #337ab7;
    color: rgba(111, 36, 36, 0);
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.slick-next {
    right: -25px;
}
```

I checked and turn off all class parent have contained `z-index`.
I set max number of fields `z-index`:

`<button>Next</button>`.

You can see more information at here:

[image]

Comment: The problem could be that slick-next is at the top within slick-track, but slick-track itself is not visible. I am not sure if this is the way how it works.

Comment: tried `overflow: visible !important`

Comment: @weinde . I tried. `Overflow: visible !important` is not working for me.

Comment: Could you share the live link? Or share this code using jsfiidle/codepen or anything like that?

Comment: child elements inherits the `z-index` from its parent, that `z-index` in button is unnecessary. The stack order applies between siblings.

Comment: @vanloc are you able to click the next button?

Comment: I can't click the next button. When I tried to inspect element, I found it at this position but click it not active.

Comment: can you change :
.slick-next {
    right: -25px;
}
to right :0px ?

Comment: My purposive is `slick-next` button is not shown in the carousel. I must change to `.slick-next { right: -25px; }`

Comment: Maybe the problem is the arrow, try deleting  `font-size: 0`,`line-height: 0`  and set alpha 1 in `color` to can show the text in the `button`. If you can see the text the problem is in `.slick-arrow` class, I suppose it has a background image with the arrow.

Comment: Where your website Link or JSfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the CSS:

1. font size is set to 0.
2. instead of `width`, provide `padding` to the button.

Please make following changes in CSS:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next{    
    line-height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 20px; 
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #a94442;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #337ab7;color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```